# How do I add a default value for field in CKRecord when deploy changes to production?

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

The problem is following:

Currently I have a `Service` record type in cloud dashboard in **development mode**:

[image]

But the first version of this was **WITHOUT** `createdAt` field.

I did deploy first version to **production mode** and it was fine. Then I changed `Service` by adding `createdAt` field. And I did deploy it to production. So in production I have a fields like this:

[image]

there is no `createdAt` date.

And while I develop the app and try to fetch all `Service` records... everything is fine. They are fetched and working in the app. So I deploy changes to production mode, submit app to app store. Apple did review it... and... it is not working. **WHY?**

They do not have default `createdAt` value... and when I fetch all of them... nothing is fetched (because nothing appear in the app).

But...

when I manually update `createdAt` in **PRODUCTION MODE** as you can see:

[image]

Then the app from AppStore works fine, and those records are fetched and appear in the app.

What may be the reason, that they do not appear in the app?
Can I somehow set default value for those who are in cloud currently?

I have 638 records to update:(

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you told me you have to use your custom `createdAt` date, instead of the `CKRecord`'s natural `creationDate` property, you should be able to do something like this:

```
func getServiceRecords() {
    let predicate:NSPredicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
    let query:CKQuery = CKQuery(recordType: "Service", predicate: predicate)

    // Create an empty array of CKRecords to append ones without createdAt value
    var empty:[CKRecord] = []

    // Perform the query
    if let database = self.publicDatabase {

        database.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil, completionHandler: { (records:[CKRecord]?, error:Error?) -> Void in

            // Check if there is an error
            if error != nil {

            }
            else if let records = records {

                for record in records {
                    if let _ = record.object(forKey: "createdAt") as! Date? {
                        // This record already has assigned creationDate and shouldnt need changing
                    } else {
                        // This record doesn't have a value create generic one and append it to empty array
                        record.setObject(Date() as CKRecordValue?, forKey: "createdAt")
                        empty.append(record)
                    }
                }

                self.saveCustomCreationDates(records: empty)
            }

        })

    }
}

func saveCustomCreationDates(records: [CKRecord]) {
    if let database = self.publicDatabase {

        // Create a CKModifyRecordsOperation
        let operation = CKModifyRecordsOperation(recordsToSave: records, recordIDsToDelete: nil)
        operation.savePolicy = .allKeys
        operation.qualityOfService = .userInteractive
        operation.allowsCellularAccess = true
        operation.modifyRecordsCompletionBlock = { (records:[CKRecord]?, deleted:[CKRecordID]?, error:Error?) in
            if error != nil {
               // Handle error
            }
            else if let records = records {

                for record in records {

                    if let creationDate = record.object(forKey: "createdAt") as! Date? {
                        // You can verify it saved if you want
                        print(creationDate)
                    }
                }

            }

        }
        // Add the operation
        database.add(operation)
    }

}
```

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk - Let me know if this won't work for you, and you have to do it the way you're trying without the `CKRecord`'s natural `creationDate`, I have an idea of how to solve your problem but it seems like it's unnecessary to me.

Comment: I know, but I need here the date when it was created on the phone, not when it was synced with cloud... it doesnt have to be the same...

Comment: Ok give me a minute. I will edit my answer to something I think might work.

Comment: so, do I need to do this in code? There is no way through dashboard?

Comment: You could, but you'd have to do it one by one. If you don't have any user data stored, you could just delete the Record and then re-create it with all the same names, but I don't recommend that, especially if you have ANY user data already saved as it will all be lost.

Comment: I've had to do similar things before to mass-edit records after deployment. What I usually do is write the code, call the method inside my main `viewDidLoad` while testing on my phone, wait until I get a response that it worked, then just comment out the code or delete it so you don't risk running the operation twice.

Comment: Can I really iterate over all records of ALL users and save records with `createdAt`? In development mode?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132942/discussion-between-pierce-and-bartlomiej-semanczyk).